# How to keep the prompt after running some commands?

Tags: ruby, command-line, irb

I run a script using Launchy which  opens an html document in the internet browser.
the browser becomes the active window and I lose the prompt on irb.

how can I keep the prompt ?

Comment: What command does Launchy use to open the html document in the browser?

Comment: Launchy.open ('URL')

Answer (score 0):

Use Kernel#spawn : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn

```
spawn('./launch_url.rb')
```

Where the file ./launch_url.rb contains (and you have executable rights on it) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'launchy'
Launchy.open ('URL')
```